# difference between Heat and temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

Temperature is often said to be average kinetic energy of the atoms and heat the sum of kinetic energy of all atoms.

I dont agree with this definition of Heat as Heat is NOT energy. It is mode of energy transfer i.e. it is energy in transit. Once it is in System you can't distinguish between heat or work or any other form of energy. So temperature is avg kinetic energy and heat is energy in transit. is that right.?

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53740/whats-the-basic-difference-between-heat-and-temperature?rq=1

Comment: "heat the sum of kinetic energy of all atoms" -- Where did you see heat defined this way? As you say, in thermodynamics I've always seen heat defined as energy transferred spontaneously from one body to another, not something possessed by a given body (see the definition [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/heat.html) for example).

Comment: Your first line is not universally true: it is true *e.g.* of an ideal gas and is a high temperature approximation for an ensemble of thermalised quantum harmonic oscillators, for example. See the links Kyle gives you.

Comment: What you "agree with" is completely irrelevant to reality. If you don't understand something, ask a direct question, but don't push your own level of ignorance first. That's just some general advice about learning.

Comment: heat is a form of kinetic and potential energy of a system. it is stored in a random motion of microscopic constituents of a system. Temperature can be proportional to a kinetic energy of these constituents but it is not the same. Temperature measures the ability of a system to transfer heat to another system..higher the temperature, faster the transfer. System can have more thermal energy but less temperature..for example a glass of water at 350 K and an olympic pool at 200 K. Olympic pool has more energy but transfer of heat goes from glass to the pool.